# In .Net core 2.0 when I send a POST Request to my controller the data does not bind to the object I have used. How do I bind this data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

**Here is my Post() method**

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("Application/Json")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Album value)
{
    if(value==null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Album cannot be empty");
    }
    if(value.AlbumName==null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Album Name cannot be empty");
    }
    else if(value.AlbumName.Equals(""))
    {
        return BadRequest("Album Name cannot be empty");
    }
    if (value.AlbumReleasedate == null||value.AlbumReleasedate.Equals("") )
    {
        return BadRequest("Album Release Date cannot be empty");
    }
    if (value.CoverImageURL.Equals("") || value.CoverImageURL == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Cover Image URL cannot be empty");
    }

    return Ok(value);

}
```

and this is the Album Class

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumId;
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public string CoverImageURL { get; set; }
    public DateTime AlbumReleasedate { get; set; }
    public Artist  artist;
    public List<Song> Songs;
}
```

here value.AlbumName is null.
when i send this request with Body using POSTMAN

```
{
 "Album":{
        "coverImageURL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_Go_",
        "albumReleasedate": "2002-06-04T00:00:00",
        "albumName": "Let Go."
    }
}
```

when I send a POST Request to my controller the data does not bind to the object i have used. How do i bind this data?

Comment: Probably you don't have to nest the `Album` attribute. Try to post just this: `{
        "coverImageURL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_Go_",
        "albumReleasedate": "2002-06-04T00:00:00",
        "albumName": "Let Go."
    }`

Comment: ya it works thank you

Answer (score 1):

ema is right. You don't need the Album key. Just remove that and it'll work

```
{ "coverImageURL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_Go_", "albumReleasedate": "2002-06-04T00:00:00", "albumName": "Let Go." }
```